# How to soft delete a Model in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a table of `Advertisements`, I need to delete a record temporarily that can be enabled again and I can also fetch the deleted results.

Comment: Add an 'active' column, set it to false for "deleted" items.

Comment: That wil be a long process like using a falg but I think there is an option of soft deleted in laravel-4 that disable the deleted rows in select. But I don't know how can I use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add soft delete trait in your Advertisement.php (Advertisement model)

**For soft delete:**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Advertisement extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait; 

    .....
}
```

Next, you need to add a column in table deleted_at (timestamp, default null), now when you normally delete your Advertisement

```
$advertisement = Advertisement::find($id);
$advertisement->delete();
```

It will add current timestamp in deleted_at column, and that particular row will not be fetched until deleted_at column has value.

**For get all soft deleted values:**

```
$deletedAdvertisement = Advertisement::onlyTrashed()->get();
```

**you can use documentation for more info:**

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete

Comment: Thanks @Anshul Mishra

Answer (score 2):

If you have created your table using migrations you need to add this to the migration file :

```
$table->softDeletes();
```

here's more about migrations : http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations#creating-migrations

One the migration created and run you need to attach your table to a an `Ad` model and your model need to use `SoftDeletingTrait` like this :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Ad extends Eloquent {

  use SoftDeletingTrait;
  protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
  // ...

}
```

And now when querying the model "deleted" models will not be included in query results, if you want so, you could you `withTrashed()` method like this :

```
 Ad::withTrashed()->all();
```

if you want only the deleted one use :

```
 Ad::onlyTrashed()->all();
```

For more info about soft deleting : http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#soft-deleting